# Enable new permission dialog

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

How to enable the new oauth permission/install dialog? Any actual url will be helpful.

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: what you mean ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ or http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/

Comment: Rufinus the second one displays "Something went wrong" ... and the first one still displays the old layout ... i guess it's not available for yet (facebook's fault)

Comment: strange for me the link is working, and prints the page for the post to timeline (beta) widget.

Comment: can you try that with another account ?

Comment: ah strange.. logout same error as you, logedin, no result at all. (loading bar is displayed, then white page) as whole facebook is beta, then something fb calls beta must be early alpha :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apps Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Edit your App > Settings > Advanced > Migrations section > Enable "*Enhanced Auth Dialog*"

Comment: Thank you, I should make my questions more clear, I already do that , still displays the old dialog because I am using location.top.href=static url ... could  you example url to fit it in my needs

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're testing with a Facebook account that isn't logged as a developer or test user of the app. If you're using a Facebook user not associated with your app the old dialogs will still display to you.

Go to the roles section of your app, create a test user, switch to that user and start testing again.

Comment: yes, just wondering when it will be available for all facebook users